# How to Get the homepage url captured by linkbutton in sp2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a website in sp 2010, in which I need to add a Home button on one of the webpages, which can redirect to home page . The requirement is that, i cannot use hardcoded URL for the home page. I have tried using linkbuton using postback url property but cant get it right. Please provide me suggestions or solution.

Comment: Can you explain the "requirement"? Why not just use a hard-coded URL to link to an absolute page? That would certainly be the easiest and most straight-forward solution. Is this homework for a course or assignment?

Comment: @teylyn we are not allowed to used hard coded values, in order to follow best practices. Also this is a part of course assignmnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a javascript command:

```
var baseUrl = location.protocol +'//'+ document.location.hostname
```

or

```
var baseUrl = location.origin
```

e.g.: if your current url is *http://server1/sites/test1/Lists* the commands above will give you *http://server1*

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using the below code on button click

'string URL = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

Response.Redirect(URL);'